# SSIS script task namespace has junk number

Tags: ssis

I have one script task inside foreach loop container. script task namespace has random number (looks like GUID). I changed "ScriptProjectName" property but project name is not changed. Please help me how to change this.

Comment: why you want to change that? It's a system generated project name and only be effective in the package. In other words you won't be able to reuse it else where like you do in a proper c# project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thotwielder commented. Why you want rename it. As it is SSIS package generated and when your SSIS package will refer script task this will be dine only via GUID whihc you can in xml code of package. Because SSIS package is nothing but a XML code with different component.

SSIS processing engine read that xml and process accordingly. So GUID for script task component will only be identified by SSIS processing system internally.

Comment: Hoa can I do that? I can change the name of the assembly, but not the namespace identifier.